# Scripts don't load: Using AngularJS with JSON (Firebase)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I've tried to build an application that let's you input data into several fields, uses AngularJS to put data into a Firebase JSON, and outputs that data into nicely laid out "cards".

Initially I could input and output data, but as soon as I hooked it up to AngularJS and Firebase I just got '{{ 1 + 2 }}' instead of '3' in my browser.

I'm running this code on my webserver, I hope you can help me figure out what the problem is – the page is pretty much blank. Everything that depends on Angular isn't showing up.

Link to live page:

[repertoire.me/anustart](http://repertoire.me/anustart/)

Here's my code:

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="repertoire">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Repertoire Beta</title>

    <!-- STYLES -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/venues.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

  <body ng-controller="VenueController as venueCtrl">

    <p class="ANGULAR_TEST">1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 }}</p>

    <header class="card">
        <h1>repertoire</h1>
    </header>

    <venue-list></venue-list>

    <venue-form></venue-form>

    <footer id="info" class="card" ng-include="'footer.html'"></footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

**venue-list.html**

```
<section class="card" id="venueList">
<h2 class="venue_name">{{venueCtrl.venue.name}}</h2>
<h3 class="venue_location">{{venueCtrl.venue.location}}</h3>
<div class="pricecat">
    <span class="venue_price">{{venueCtrl.venue.price}}</span>
    <span class="venue_category">{{venueCtrl.venue.species}} {{venueCtrl.venue.genre}}</span>
</div>
<p class="venue_description">{{venueCtrl.venue.description}}</p>
<p class="venue_tags">{{venueCtrl.venue.tags}}</p>
</section>
```

**venue-form.html**

```
<section class="card" id="venueForm">
<form name="venueForm" ng-controller="VenueController as venueCtrl" ng-submit="venueForm.$valid && venueCtrl.venueForm(info)" novalidate>
    <input ng-model="venueCtrl.venue.name" type='text' class="input" id='nameInput' placeholder='Venue Name' required/>
    <input ng-model="venueCtrl.venue.location" type='text' class="input" id='locationInput' placeholder='Address' required/>
    <select ng-model="venueCtrl.venue.price" type='text' class="input" id='priceInput' ng-options="price for price in [$,$$,$$$,$$$$]">
        <option value="">Price</option>
    </select>
    <input ng-model="venueCtrl.venue.genre" type='text' class="input" id='genreInput' placeholder='Category'/>
    <input ng-model="venueCtrl.venue.species" type='text' class="input" id='speciesInput' placeholder='What kind?'/>
    <textarea ng-model="venueCtrl.venue.description" type='text' class="input" id='descriptionInput' placeholder='Description'></textarea>
    <input ng-model="venueCtrl.venue.tags" type='text' class="input" id='tagsInput' placeholder='Who did you go with?'/>
    <label>Have you already been?</label>
    <input ng-model="venueCtrl.venue.check" type="checkbox" checked />

    <div> venueForm is {{venueForm.$valid}} </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Venue"/>
</form>
</section>
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('repertoire', ['repertoire-venues']);

//var app = new Firebase('https://xyz.firebaseio.com/');

app.controller("VenueController", ['$http', function($http){
    var venue = this;
    venue.info = [ ];

    $http.get('venues.json').success(function(data){
        venue.info = data;
    });
}]);

})();
```

**repertoire-venues.js**

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('repertoire-venues', []);

app.directive('venueList', function(){
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       templateUrl: 'venue-list.html'
   }; 
});

app.directive('venueForm', function(){
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       templateUrl: 'venue-form.html'
       controller: function(){
           this.venue = {};

           this.venueForm = function(info){
               info.venues.push(this.venue);
               this.venue = {};
            };
       },
       controllerAs: 'venueCtrl'
   }; 
});

})();
```

Thank you so much <3

Comment: Why are you loading angualrjs multiple times?

Comment: are there any errors on console?

Comment: I couldn't get angularJS to work to I tried to load it via bootstrap too. @Satpal

Comment: @Giwwel the console is complaining about me loading angular three times... sorry I've only started learning about Angular and JSON 3 days ago, I'm trying to figure out where I went horribly wrong

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the errors you are seeing? You are loading Angular 3 times, which isn't needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have included venues.js instead of repertoire-venues.js in the index page and there is a comma missing on line 14 in repertoire-venues.js

Comment: the file is called venues.js